# Is the difference of the return of two stocks univariate or multivariate?

Tags: time-series, finance

I'm trying to figure out which stationarity test should apply to a time serie. In order to do it, I need to understand the difference of univariate and multivariate.

Is the difference (or in a general way, the function) of two stocks' returns multivariate (because depends on two stocks) or univariate (because only depends on time)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Univariate. You have one variable, stock1-stock2.

That's why it's uni (one) variate. In your case, it's a time series, but time has nothing to do with whether it's univariate (one data series) or not.